# Downloading files with SMB

Tags: python-2.7, smb

I'm trying to download a CSV through my network share using the *pysmbclient* module, but I'm getting an error (below). The server is Win2003 R2 (DFS), it's a IPC$ share. I'm able to authenticate OK and download the file through Windows Explorer on my main account. The only difference is my main account pulls it with "**Trans 2 Request, QUERY_PATH_INFO**".

Is there a "pure python" way of doing this over SMB?

```
import smbclient

userID = 'user'
password = 'password'
server_name = 'usa03'
ip = '10.1.13.211'

try:
    smb = smbclient.SambaClient(server=server_name, ip=ip, share="share", username=userID, password=password, domain='biz')
    f = smb.open('\sas\results\summary.csv')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
except:
        print "No go"
smb.close()
```

SMB 286 Open AndX Request, Path: \sas\results\summary.csv

SMB 93  Open AndX Response, Error: STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that `\r` is being interpreted as [a control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Change the path to:

```
f = smb.open('\\sas\\results\\summary.csv')
```

You should also, where possible, avoid `except:` and instead catch specific exceptions.

You could also use a `finally:` clause here:

```
try:
    smb = smbclient.SambaClient(server=server_name, ip=ip, share="share", 
                                username=userID, password=password, domain='biz')
    with smb.open('\\sas\\results\\summary.csv') as f:
        data = f.read()
except SomeError: # not literally SomeError but an error you might encounter
    print "No go"
finally:
    smb.close()
```

Comment: I changed them all to double slashes and that worked, thanks! It's odd that Wireshark was interpreting it as a literal backslash.

Comment: You're very welcome. It's normal behaviour. You can't do that within Python either.